# No read permission on 'MSysObjects' (Error No: -2147217911) when Using Microsoft Excel VBA to Query Access accdb files only - mdb works fine

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

No read permission on 'MSysObjects' (Error No: -2147217911) when Using Microsoft Excel VBA to Query Access accdb files only - mdb works fine

Using Microsoft Excel VBA to Query Access.

With an mdb file this connection string opens the mdb file fine and the SQL String returns the tables I want.

```
Connection String: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C:\My Files\Word\ADA II Text\Chapters\9 -



8\Access\ADAIICH9TEST.mdb";User Id=admin;Password=;
SQL String: SELECT MSysObjects.Name From MSysObjects WHERE MSysObjects.Name Not Like "MSyS*" And Type=1 AND 

Flags=0 ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

With an accdb file this connection string opens the accdb file fine but the SQL throws the following error:

Error No: -2147217911       Error Desc: Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.

Why does it have access to MSysObjects when reading the mdb file but not the accdb file?
How do I grant access either programmatically or from within the Access File?

I have already tried executing the following statements prior to running the SQL:

```
'cn.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
'cn.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON TABLE MSysObjects TO PUBLIC;"
```

They throw the error:
Error No: -2147467259       Error Desc: Cannot open the Microsoft Access database engine workgroup information

file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Access you need to give permission for the default user to access the table.

In the immediate window with Access execute

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
```

And your SQL will work after that.

You might want to change your connection string.  IIRC Jet won't work after Access 2003 so try

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\...ADAIICH9TEST.accdb;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I was running the SQL in Excel to Access, not within Access. That was my issue. You saved me a great deal of time.